# If $f$ is holomorphic in $D = \Bbb D\cap\{\Re(z)>0\}$, $f(a)=a$ for $a\in D$ and $f(D)\subset D$, how to show that $|f'(a)|\le 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Consider $D = \{z\in\Bbb C : |z|<1,\;\Re(z)>0\}$. Take $a\in D$ and consider $f$ a holomorphic function in $D$ such that $f(a)=a$ and $f(D)\subset D$. How can we prove that $|f'(a)|\le 1$?

I've been thinking about using Schwarz's lemma with $g(z) = f\circ T(z)$, with a Möbius transformation $T$ such that $T(0)=a$. We would have that $g(\Bbb D)\subset D \subset \Bbb D$ and $g$ would be holomorphic. So $|g'(0)|\le 1$ by the Schwarz lemma, but $g'(0) = f'(a)T'(0)$.

How do I find $T$ such that $T(0)=a$ and $T'(0)=1$? If this is not good, how else should I approach this?

Comment: There is a small mismatch between question title and body: Is the real part positive or negative?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice, it's the one in the title. I'll edit it now, thank you for noticing and telling me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Möbius transformation which maps the unit disk $\Bbb D$ onto the half-disk $D$ (because Möbius transformations map disks to disks or half-planes).

But you don't need a Möbius transformation for this purpose, only *some* conformal mapping $\phi: \Bbb D\to D$ with $\phi(0) = a$. And that exists according to the [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) because $D$ is simply connected.

Then $g = \phi^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi$ maps the unit disk into itself with $g(0) = 0$, so that the Schwarz lemma can be applied to $g$. It follows that $|g'(0)| \le 1$, and that leads to the expected result.

In other words: The conclusion $|f'(a)| \le 1$ holds for any function $f$ mapping a simply-connected domain $D$ into itself and has the fixed-point $a \in D$.

Comment: So it works for any conformal function, I see. Thank you so much!